# function to subset n vector giving error message "incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r

I was making a function to extract a value from a vector given its position in the vector.

```
func_name <- function(input_vec, input_n) {
  sort(input_vec)
  if(input_n > input_vec) {
    return("Warning: input_n exceeds vector length")
  }
  else {
    return(input_vec[,c(input_n)][input_vec == input_n])
    }
}
input_vector <- c(1,2,30,40,50,60)
func_name(input, 3)
```

I am trying to get the output 30, such that the function extracts the third element from the vector. When I run the function, I get the following error message:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in input_vec[, c(input_n)] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I then read the error message and figured there might be conflicts running this with an ifelse statement so I tried the following:

```
find_largestN <- function(input_vec, input_n) {
  sort(input_vec) 
  if(input_n < input_vec) {   
  return(input_vec[,c(input_n)][input_vec == input_n])
  }
  else {
    break
}
}
```

For this, I got the following error message.

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in find_largestN(input_vec, 1) : 
  no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

I thought that this would have simplified it and reduced the chance of error but clearly it didn't work. Are there any recommendations to subset within an if else statement or function?

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: i think you are looking for function `ifelse` which takes vector as input, `if` and `else` considers only the first element of vector

Comment: Your condition makes a pretty straightforward error: you use `input_n > input_vec`, which does **not** check if `input_n` exceeds the length of `input_vec`, but rather creates a logical vector of comparisons — like `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)` when `input_vec` is `c(1, 2, 30, 40, 50, 60)` and `n = 3` — and since `if` can only evaluate one `TRUE`/`FALSE` at a time, it displays the warning `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer by [Skaqqs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10021876), you need to use `length()` for the correct condition: `input_n > length(input_vec)`.

Comment: You also make one additional error, this time in your `return()` statement: where you should simply subscript (`input_vec[input_n]`), you instead treat the vector `input_vec` as if it were a `matrix`: `input_vec[,c(input_n)]`. Naturally, treating a 1-dimensional vector as a 2-dimensional `matrix` will give you the error: `Error in input_vec[, c(input_n)] : incorrect number of dimensions`.

Comment: Even if the latter attempt succeeded rather than throwing an error, I'm still unsure why one would subscript _that_ result, using the logical vector `input_vec == input_n`, which tells you whether (`TRUE`) or not (`FALSE`) each element in `input_vec` is equal to `input_n`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly about the difference between `ifelse` and `if/else`.

`ifelse` is a vectorised method, it takes a vector as an input and produces the vector of the same length.

```r
x = rnorm(10)
ifelse(x > 0 , "positive", "negative")
#>  [1] "positive" "negative" "positive" "positive" "negative" "negative"
#>  [7] "positive" "positive" "positive" "negative"

if(x>0) "positive" else negative
#> Warning in if (x > 0) "positive" else negative: the condition has length > 1 and
#> only the first element will be used
#> [1] "positive"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But in the case of `if/else`, `if` only takes length 1 logical vector. For vectors greater than length 1, the first element is used for checking the condition and a warning is thrown, as you can see from the above example.

Looking at your code, it appears you are checking the `if` condition to compare the length of vector with provided index. So it should be:

```r
func_name <- function(input_vec, input_n) {
  if(length(input_vec) < input_n) {
    return("Warning: input_n exceeds vector length")
  }
  else {
    sort(input_vec)
    input_vec[input_n]
  }
}
input_vector <- c(1,2,30,40,50,60)
func_name(input_vector, 3)
#> [1] 30
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also note that I have put `sort(input_vec)` inside else as it makes sense to sort only when the condition is met, bit of optimization tip.

Answer (score 1):

Very close! I needed to add `length()` to your if statement

```
func_name <- function(input_vec, input_n) {
  sort(input_vec)
  if(input_n > length(input_vec)) {
    return("Warning: input_n exceeds vector length")
  }
  else {
    return(input_vec[input_n])
  }
}
```

Others have recommended `ifelse()`. That could look something like

```
ifelse(
   test = input_n > length(input_vec),
   yes = print("input_n exceeds vector length"),
   no = input_vec[input_n])
```